How can I resolve a /media URL in new links and path aliases with the media instead of a link to the media?
On Drupal 10.3.5, I have the latest dev version of Linkit enabled. I followed the instructions for enabling point directly to the media (https://www.drupal.org/docs/extending-drupal/contributed-modules/contributed-module-documentation/linkit/link-media-directly-to-the-actual-file-not-the-media-route). I also have the option for standalone media URLs enabled.
A link such as /media/2983 takes me to a page containing a URL for the media file, instead of the media file, itself.
Am I missing something?
My thinking on this has evolved. I wasn’t accounting for the difference between adding new links, which linkit could handle, and pre-existing path aliases with /media as a path. I’d like to be able to handle both when they are rendered.

Yes. I think you are missing something. I don’t understand what “A link such as /media/2983…” has to do with the part about Linkit, which is a ckeditor plugin. Media URLs exist and are a different thing.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/extending-drupal/contributed-modules/contributed-module-documentation/linkit/link-media-directly-to-the-actual-file-not-the-media-route It provides a matcher to allow linking directly to the media, or so it says and has a config option for, with an example media/###

I’m thinking that instead of that I need to create an event subscriber to redirect alias requests that have a media path to the file’s url?

I think there are actually two contexts. That the Linkit function provides the desired result for newly added media links, but the event subscriber would also handle all media url requests, including pre-existing path alias entries with a /media path

Based on the above I’ve reworded the question.

The event subscriber works. I would be interested in knowing if anyone feels there is a better approach.
